# Typeerror: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Paragraph found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docx

I am using below code to open a doc file and store the paragraphs as a string in a Django view.

```
 doc = docx.Document('media/%s'%(filename))
 fulltext = []
 for para in doc.paragraphs:
     fulltext.append(para)
 docdata1 ='\n'.join(fulltext)
```

I am getting an error

```
Typeerror: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Paragraph found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str.join` method expects a list of strings, and yet you're giving it a list of `Paragraph` objects. You should retrieve the `text` attribute of the `Paragraph` objects to append to `fulltext` instead:

```
fulltext.append(para.text)
```